# External ActionScript Only Executed When Testing Single Scene

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

New to AS 3.0 and I seem to have an issue where an external AS file is run when I test an individual scene in Flash Pro but not when I test the entire movie or when I test from Flash Builder. Anyone know what the problem might be?

Here's the code from the AS file:

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Level1 extends MovieClip {

    public var myplayer:MyPlayer;

    public function Level1() {
        super();

        myplayer.x = 516;
        myplayer.y = 371;


        if (myplayer.x == 516)

        { 
            trace("player x is 516");       
        }

        else if (myplayer.y == 371)
        {   
            trace("player y is 371");
        }

    }
}
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I think I figured out the problem. The swf contained two scenes, and the external AS file started running at the start of Scene 1, but the `myPlayer` movie clip was not instantiated until *Scene2*, which, I think was causing the problem I was having, in addition to giving a `1009 null object error`.

So I simply deleted the first scene, and now everything works fine. Maybe I will put that first scene in a separate SWF? Or, is there some way to delay a script's execution until a certain scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem:

When the constructor of your doucment class runs,  `myPlayer` doesn't yet exist so it throws a `1009` runtime error and exits the constructor at the first reference to `myPlayer`.

Solutions:

1. Put all the `myPlayer` code on the first frame of the `MyPlayer` timeline.  OR use your current document class as the class file for `MyPlayer` (instead of documentClass).  Change all references to `myPlayer` to `this`.
2. Listen for frame changes and check until `myPlayer` is populated, then run your code.

   ```
   this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);

   function enterFrameHandler(e):void {
       if(myPlayer){
           //run the myPlayer code
           this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrameHandler);
       }
   }
   ```

   If your frame rate is 24fps, this code though will run 24 times every second (until it finds `myPlayer`), so it's not the most performant way to go.
3. Use events.   Add an event to the first frame of `myPlayer` (or to a class file for `MyPLayer`) that tells the document class that it exists now.

   ```
   stage.dispatchEvent(new Event("myPlayerReady"));
   ```

   Then listen for that event on the document class:

   ```
   stage.addEventListener("myPlayerReady",playerReadyHandler);

   playerReadyHandler(e:Event):void {
       //your player code
       var myPlayer = MyPlayer(e.target); //you can even get the reference from the event object
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your constructive, helpful responses, LDMS. I thought I had found a solution when I hadn't. Your advice worked. What I did was add the following code to the timeline of MyPlayer

```
        this.x = 516;
        this.y = 371;


        if (this.x == 516)

        { 
            trace("player x is 516");       
        }

        if (this.y == 371)
        {   
            trace("player y is 371");
        }
```

and I removed the code from the document class. Everything seems to be working fine now. Thanks again for your help!